# How to write a custom ES sink in Flume 1.7

Tags: flume, agent

In the Flume agent I am collection the elements from Kafka topics and I need to insert them in ES. However I need to perform a previous digestion process in the sink, so I need to write a custom sink to pass the data from the Agent's channel to a java digestion module (which I have written already).

Can anyone share with me a template of a custom sink and can use as a reference? Flumes official website doesn't say much about this topic: 
*A custom sink’s class and its dependencies must be included in the agent’s classpath when starting the Flume agent. The type of the custom sink is its FQCN.*
https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#custom-sink

And once the custom sink is ready, How could I link the following three files to make the agent work:

- custom sink
- ingestion jar (java module to perform the ingestion process)
- FlumeAgent.properties

Thank you for any feedback. I will keep adding information as soon as I progress in this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope you are trying to use Flume to recieve events from Kafka (source) and forwarding it to ES (sink) with some data processing logic already you have.

With this understanding, I would suggest you to look into Flume interceptors which is responsible for altering/filtering the events on fly before sending to Sink.

So all your business logic to alter the events can be implemented as a custom interceptor and it should be configured to the Flume channel.

For reference you can checkout the [native interceptors source code](https://github.com/apache/flume/tree/trunk/flume-ng-core/src/main/java/org/apache/flume/interceptor) already available. This should probably give you an idea on the Flume interceptor framework.

Here is the [ES Sink source code](https://github.com/apache/flume/tree/trunk/flume-ng-sinks/flume-ng-elasticsearch-sink/src/main/java/org/apache/flume/sink/elasticsearch)

**Sample Flume config**

```
a1.sources = kafkaSource
a1.sinks = ES_Sink
a1.channels = channel1

a1.sources.kafkaSource.interceptors = i1
a1.sources.kafkaSource.interceptors.i1.type = org.apache.flume.interceptor.<Custom_Interceptor_name>$Builder

a1.sinks.ES_Sink.channel = channel1
a1.sinks.ES_Sink.type = elasticsearch
a1.sinks.ES_Sink.hostNames = 127.0.0.1:9200
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback!